# Rails (ActiveRecord) many to many table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, many-to-many

I have two models, Users and Groups. Each group can have many users and each user can be in many groups.

I currently have something simple like:

User:

```
has_many    :groups
```

Group:

```
has_many    :users
```

So I have a groups_users table which is just creating rows with group_id and user_id.
I want to add another column to this, (which I have), the question is how do I access it from a model without using a custom SQL call? In the group model I can go self.users and in user I can go self.groups

Is there a way to change the third column in this table from a user model?

Sorry if this is confusing, please advise on this

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here are a couple of tutorials that should help.  Basically there two approaches to make many-to-many work, either has_and_belongs_to_many or has_many :through (recommended).

links:

1. http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2006/4/20/many-to-many-dance-off
2. http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many
3. http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association

Comment: Especially the 2nd link. Great example of has_and_belongs_to_many in action.

Comment: Are those links are still relevant =?

Answer (score 13):

In Rails 3 you want to make a join table for many to many relationships, using the plural names of the tables you want to join in alphabetical order. So in this case it would be `groups_users`.

## models

```
class GroupsUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups_users
  has_many :groups, :through => :groups_users
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups_users
  has_many :users, :through => :groups_users
end
```

Comment: Would be interesting to know how to access a related field in view

Answer (score 4):

> I [added] another column to [`users_groups`]...The question is how do
>   I access it from a model without using
>   a custom SQL call?

It sounds like you want to access a column of your `user_groups` table by calling a method on your `User` model or your `Group` model.

Some suggestions:

I'd name the table "`user_groups`" to work with ActiveRecord's pluralization expectations, but I'm not sure if that's essential.

Following Dave's advice, you'd want to set things up using the "`has_many :through`" technique...

```
# Declare a Model based on the many-to-many linking table.
class UserGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_groups
  has_many :groups, :through => :user_groups
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_groups
  has_many :users, :through => :user_groups
end
```

> Is there a way to change the third column in this table from a user model?

This is a little unclear, but keep in mind that each `User` can have a lot of `UserGroups`. So if you wanted to change that third column you'd have to find the particular one you're looking for.

Comment: If you don't need any extra data in the UserGroup table, then skip its ActiveRecord entirely, and use `has_and_belongs_to_many` associations between User and Group with a join table. See the second link on the other answer.

Comment: in django, it is easy to add a third column to a many to many helper table: you just add the field to the model which you also access by "through". Another column in your example is helpful if you e. g. want to give the user a certain state (active or not) in the group.